# How do you import a database through lando?

Tags: 8

I am trying to setup a site within lando and need to import the database. How do you import a database through lando?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lando db-import <path to sql or sql.gz or .zip file here>` will do that for you.

`db-import` will drop all tables before performing the import.  it has a `--no-wipe` flag that can be used if you *don't* want to drop tables first.

More information in the documentation: https://docs.lando.dev/guides/db-import.html

Answer (score 0):

We need to run the following two commands to import database (to an existing site)

```
lando drush sql-drop
lando db-import <dbname>.gz
```

Comment: Can also use `pv` to import database if you want to see progress in the lando container from windows (via git bash). so lando file `services:
  database:
    build_as_root:
      - 'apt-get update'
      - 'apt-get install pv'` and then use: `sql_file=./path/to/file.sql.gz` and `size=$(wc -c $sql_file | awk '{print $1}')` and finally `cat $sql_file | lando ssh --service database -c "pv -f -s $size | gunzip | mysql -u drupal7 -pdrupal7 drupal7"`